# Svetle routing works in-app but not directly in browser

Tags: routes, svelte, rollup

I'm a real noob so I hope my question doesn't offend anyone :)
My routing in Svelte seems to work fine when I navigate in-app, but not when I insert the url directly to the browser (getting 404). I saw many answers that suggested to add "sirv public --single" to the package.json file and I did, but the problem persist.

I suspect my rollup config might be the issue, but have no idea as to how to fix or even validate this assumption. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen when you run the app locally on your dev machine (because then, adding `sirv public --single` should do the job. If your question is about running it on some hosting environment (e.g. in production), you have to adjust something there.

Comment: That only works for SSR, if you only have a SPA this won't work/is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by changing my routing to "svelte-spa-router" that uses hash-based routing

Comment: That's cool but what if you don't want hash-based routing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `svelte-router` library and I replaced it with [svelte-navigator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-navigator), It uses the same syntax as `svelte-router`.